# How to refer to waves/charges/offensives in a battle?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I want to find a term to complete this sentence:

> Enemy morale fell after the second _______ was carried out.

Maybe a better way to understand what I'm after is imagine we break up the army into divisions. 1st corresponds to the front line, 2nd would be those who mount an offensive right after, and so forth. The trouble is when googling "2nd brigade" and related terms, the numbers don't really correspond to that, it's more of a proper noun if I understand it correctly. So any attempt I try to twist these terms for my own use runs the risk of people familiar with military lingo being confused because the way I intend to use it is different that how it is conventionally used.

Any ideas or workarounds?

Comment: 'after the second phase of the attack'.

Comment: How could any Answer be anything but an opinion… of which 37 or so might well be valid here?

Comment: **wave** in the title of the question would serve as the word you need and would not confuse people familiar with military lingo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Suggestions :**

> Enemy morale fell after the second **assault** was carried out.
> Enemy morale fell after we carried out our second **onslaught**.
> Enemy morale fell after we completed our second **blitzkrieg**.
> Enemy morale fell after our second **bombardment** was completed.

**Check out :**

https://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=assault

> close fighting during the culmination of a military attack

https://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=onslaught

> (military) an offensive against an enemy (using weapons)

https://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=blitzkrieg

> (military) a swift and violent military offensive with intensive aerial bombardment
> Fight a quick and surprising war

https://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=bombardment

> The heavy fire of artillery to saturate an area rather than hit a specific target
> An attack by dropping bombs

Comment: There’s also *foray* and *raid.*

Comment: Oh , I stopped looking beyond A (Assualt) & B (Blitzkrieg) , though I am sure , many other letters may have suitable words , @Xanne , like your F (foray) & R (raid) : Eg O (Offensive) & V (Volley) !